# Problem with finding the longest word in map

Tags: kotlin, maxby

I have such a code, in general it works correctly, but if there is a maximum long word and it is followed by the same words in length, then it will return only 1 long word, and I need to get the last long word. Here's what I mean, such input: AWord BWord ALongWord BLongWord CLongWord. My code will output an (A)ALongWord but should output a (C)CLongWord because it is the most recent.

```
fun main(){
    val result1 = readLine()?.split(" ")?.associateWith { it.length }?.maxBy { it.value }.let{it?.key?.get(0)}.let { println(it) }
}
```

I assume that this can be done with reduce, but I don't quite understand how, probably my implementation needs to be redone because maxBy does not allow it to be done, if possible, fix my code or offer your solution.
This is a learning task and it involves using functions over collections.

Answer (score 5):

[`maxBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/max-by.html) finds the first occurrence of the maximum element, not the last.

If you want the last maximum element, you can simply do `maxBy` after *reversing* ([`asReversed`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/as-reversed.html)) the list of strings you got from `split`.

Consider using [`maxByOrNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/max-by-or-null.html) instead of `maxBy` so that you get a `null` instead of an exception when the user entered nothing.

Also, I'm not sure why you made a map out of this. That is unnecessary. You also shouldn't assign the result of `let { println(...) }` to a `val`. That is the `Unit` object, not the result you want.

If you want to store the result somewhere and also print it, use `also`:

```
val result = readlnOrNull()
    ?.split(" ")
    ?.asReversed()
    ?.maxByOrNull { it.length }
    ?.also { println(it) }
```